# Crystal select expert

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to use the Select Expert to generate a filter so my reports only show results when a certain OLE Image is visible.

we currently have three OLE images (shown below)

[image]

1. I want to generate a filter to create a report that only shows one of any particular OLE Image. (just the results that have a red X against it)
2. Is there a way of differentiating between OLE Images?

If you require any more information I will try and get it as soon as possible. thank you in advance!

Comment: This will depend entirely on how the image relates to your rows of data. What circumstance does a row display the red X image? What do the different images represent in the data?

Comment: When I right clicked the image and went into "Format Graphic..." and then click the second "X-2" button down in the SQL window it shows
{PROD_Product.Traffic_Status}<>0 

the others are 1 and 2 ------------- Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the images are completely dependent on `{PROD_Product.Traffic_Status}`, you can just filter the report according to this field. If you wanted to only display the rows with the red X for example, you could just add `{PROD_Product.Traffic_Status}=0` to your record selection formula (basically, the inverse of the conditional suppression formula for the images).

In reality, you'll probably just want to create a numerical parameter that contains the choices 0, 1, or 2 to represent the different traffic statuses/images and filter according to that `{PROD_Product.Traffic_Status}={?Traffic Status Parameter}`